# Project requirement to Read input files from COBOL and bring on Mosaic Platform

Tags: mosaic-decisions

I have a project requirement to read input files from COBOL, but Mosaic does not have COBOL connecter, to bring the files on to the platform.How can I bring the Files from COBOL Environment to use it for further transformations in Mosaic.

Comment: COBOL is a programming language. Which runs in many environments. Which hardware/OS environment host your COBOL created files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a custom code in `java`, which connects to COBOL source and fetch the data and finally lands it to the Blob storage, and uploaded it to my GIT repository. Using Mosaic, I have invoked this custom java code as `Pre-Hook`.

Now instead of `java`, you can also write your custom code in `python` and invoke it as `Pre-hook` or `Post-hook` using Mosaic.